# Magento 1.9: Sort product listing first by "Manufacturer" then by "Name"

Tags: magento-1.9

I got a question where I want to sort the product listings in category pages sorted by manufacturer by default then I would like it to be alphabetically by name.

Example:

Products list (Sorted by Manufacturer) - this is working

```
Product G     Product Z     Product A   Product R   Product Ab
```

Where it should be:

Products list (Sorted by Manufacturer) - this is working

```
Product A     Product Ab     Product G   Product R   Product Z
```

Same issue but it's not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167173/magento-sort-by-position-and-name

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got it working and here is how did I manage to fixed it.

I edited list.phtml and replace the line of code that stores the product collection which is:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

And replace it with this line:

```
<?php

  $cat_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
  $_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSort('manufacturer', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');

?>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you go to Category page in Magento administration (Catalog/Manage Categories), you’ll see “Display Settings” tab. From there you can modify “Available Product Listing Sort By” and “Default Product Listing Sort By” values.

Let’s modify “Default Product Listing Sort By”. If you deselect “Use Config Settings” and if you select “Manufacturer” for “Default Product Listing Sort By”, on frontend for specified category you’ll see that all items are now sorted by Name ascending (growing upward).

You can select multiple attributes for this sorting. (Manufacturer and Name)

Comment: Thanks @Irfan but you cant select multiple attributes in "Default Product Listing Sort By" here so if I choose Manufacturer on the frontend the products were not in ascending order or alphabetically order.